# Prove $a\sqrt{\frac{4+b^2+c^2}{b^2+c^2}}+b\sqrt{\frac{4+c^2+a^2}{c^2+a^2}}+c\sqrt{\frac{4+a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}}\ge \sqrt{\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{a+b+c-2}}.$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $a+b+c=ab+bc+ca>0.$ Prove that$$a\sqrt{\frac{4+b^2+c^2}{b^2+c^2}}+b\sqrt{\frac{4+c^2+a^2}{c^2+a^2}}+c\sqrt{\frac{4+a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}}\ge \sqrt{\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{a+b+c-2}}.$$
I checked that equality holds at $(a,b,c)=\{(1,1,1); (0,2,2)\}.$

Here is my attempt I've done so far.

By using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{\frac{4+b^2+c^2}{b^2+c^2}}\ge \sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\cdot(b+c+2).$$And $\sqrt{b^2+c^2}=\sqrt{(b+c)^2-2bc}\le b+c.$

Hence, we need to prove $$\sum_{cyc}a\cdot\left(1+\frac{2}{b+c}\right)\ge \sqrt{\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{a+b+c-2}}.$$
From here I didn't know how to continue.

Hope you help me. All idea and comment are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof.**

By the given condition, we have
$$\sqrt{\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{a+b+c-2}}=\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \tag{1}.$$
Now, use CBS inequality as$$\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)\left(1+\frac{4}{b^2+c^2}\right)}\ge a+2,$$
thus
$$a\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)\left(1+\frac{4}{b^2+c^2}\right)}\ge \sum_{cyc} (a^2+2a)=(a+b+c)^2.$$It implies$$a\sqrt{\frac{4+b^2+c^2}{b^2+c^2}}+b\sqrt{\frac{4+c^2+a^2}{c^2+a^2}}+c\sqrt{\frac{4+a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}}\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} .\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we complete the proof.

Comment: My solution is the same! :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, it seems obvious.